# What table stores # times a product has been viewed

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento-community

I want to manually run a query to make a specific product SKU has zero # times its been viewed. What would the table and or MySQL query be to make a specific SKU (say the SKU is abcd) have zero views instead of the number of views it currently has.

What I am trying to achieve is make the items that have the most views show up first in my Magento CE 1.9.1 catalog listing page. However, I have a few products that have high viewed but I want them to appear last because they do not sell well. So I want to manually change them to have zero views so they will show last in the sort order.

Answer (score 2):

Have you reviewed all these tables

```
report_viewed_product_index
report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily
report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly
report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly
```

Comment: That saved my day!